# How to get HTML 5 data-* values in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Assume I have this :

```
<select class="form-control" name="gateway">
  <option data-type="typeA" value="1">Test String</option>
  <option data-type="typeB" value="2">Test String</option>
  <option data-type="typeC" value="3">Test String</option>
</select>
<span>@{{ typeMapper(data-type) }}</span>
```

Here is my Vue.js script :

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',

    data: {},

    methods: {
        typeMapper: function (type) {
            var array = {
                'typeA':'You selected Type A',
                'typeB':'You selected Type B',
                'typeC':'You selected Type C',
            };
            return array[type];
        }
    }
});
```

Now how can I get `data-type` values in Vue.js ?

I want to pass selected option `data-type` value to Vue.js typeMapper method and show the result in the `span` tag.

I don't know how to pass `data-type` value to Vue.js !

P.S:

*I'm using Vue.js 2*

Comment: Do you just need to know what the data-type is of the selected option, or do you specifically need to bind to data-type for some reason?

Comment: I just need to know data-type of selected option

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't a true javascript array so I used the `Object.keys` function to grab the key names.  Here's a quick way of doing what you're looking for:

```
<div id="app">
  <select class="form-control" name="gateway">
    <option v-for="(key,index) in Object.keys(array)" :value="index+1" :data-type="key">
      {{ array[key]}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And the Vue code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array: {
      'typeA': 'You selected Type A',
      'typeB': 'You selected Type B',
      'typeC': 'You selected Type C',
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/au1vofn8/).

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue as to why you'd want to gather data sets from a given html5 structure. Since you'd usually want to get that trough ajax calls or set the select options trough some other component or whatever.

If you however want to get the elements given from a html structure you'd do something like this.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpYxJa?editors=1010)

HTML

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="vue-app">
      <select class="form-control" v-on:change="typeMapper">
      <option data-type="" value="">Select Type</option>
      <option data-type="typeA" value="1">typeA</option>
      <option data-type="typeB" value="2">typeB</option>
      <option data-type="typeC" value="3">typeC</option>
    </select>
    <span>{{ gateway }}</span>
    </div>
```

JS

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: {
      gateway: "",
    },
    methods: {
        typeMapper: function (event) {
          this.gateway = event.target[event.target.value].dataset.type;
        }
    }
});
```

This is by far from optimal or a cross browser variant. If I were you I'd scrap this approach.